# Reverse order of the Arrays stored in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, reverse

I'm working with `Processing` and `IGeo` library and I have an `ArrayList` of `IVec[]` arrays:

```
ArrayList<IVec []> v = new ArrayList<IVec[]>();
```

For every `I` of the ArrayList `I` have a collection of `IVec []` arrays that represent the coordinates of the control points of a curve. I need to reverse the order of the `IVec []` control points keeping the same order of the ArrayList (I'm trying to invert curve seam reversing control points order and keeping the original order of the curves) but I can't understand how to do this.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is working:

```
for (int i=0; i<v.size (); i++) {  
  IVec [] vert=v.get(i); 
  for (int j=0; j<vert.length/2; j++) {
    IVec temp = vert[j];
    vert[j]=vert[vert.length -1 - j];
    vert[vert.length - 1 - j] = temp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't provide you a full solution, but will guide you through it:

- Iterate on the array list `v`
- for each item in it (`IVec[]`),

  - Convert the array to a collection (for example using [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-))
  - Use [`Collections.reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-) to reverse the items in the list
  - Conver it back to an array

Comment: When I try to use Arrays.AsList I get the error _The function AsList(IVec[]) does not exist_, I supposed related to IVec[] properties but not sure. I'm trying to iterate over the ArrayList to change the index manually with the for loop.

Comment: @liuz_m it's `asList`, with small **a**.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have corrected my mistake but now I get _cannot convert from List<IVec>to List_

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Collections.reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29)

You can also use a stack data structure. You can iterate over collection you wish to reverse by `push`ing the elements into the stack. Then, when you actually want to use the elements, you `pop` each element from the stack, which will allow you to iterate over the collection in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

- Create a Helper method/function that takes and returns array.
- Inside the Helper method, use Collections.reverse
- return the reversed array.
- call this helper method inside a loop as below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < OutArray.length; I++)
{ // Here get the inner Array and pass it to Helper method. 
// Add the return array to newArray List 
}
return newArrayList.
```

Comment: This post should elaborate on the solution rather than just post code and expect users to perform blind copy-pastes with getting additional understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not the most efficient way, but easily understood):

```
public static <T> void reverseElements(ArrayList<T[]> list) {   

    ArrayList<T> tempList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T[] arr : list) {

        tempList.clear();
        for(T t : arr)
            tempList.add(t);

        Collections.reverse(tempList);
        tempList.toArray(arr);
        arr = tempList.toArray(arr);
    }       
}
```